# Multiplicative Inverse for Generating Function

Tags: combinatorics, power-series, generating-functions

I have a question based on [Irreducible and Connected Permutations](http://kam.mff.cuni.cz/~klazar/irre.pdf).

I was able to use the notion of connected permutations to construct a combinatoric proof for

\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i}(n-i)!=n!.
\end{equation}

Now let $\displaystyle F(x)=\sum_{n \geq 1} n! x^{n}$ and $\displaystyle G(x)=\sum_{n \geq 1} c_{n} x^{n}$.

I was then asked to prove that $1-G(x)$ and $1+F(x)$ are multiplicative inverses. It would seem to be an easy question but I cannot seem to see my mistake:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
(1-G(x))(1+F(x)) &= 1 \\
1 - G(x) + F(x) - G(x)F(x) &= 1 \\
1 - \sum_{n\geq 1}c_n x^n + \sum_{n \geq 1} n! x^{n}  - \sum_{n \geq 1} \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i}(n-i)! \right] x^{n}  &= 1 \\
1 - \sum_{n\geq 1}c_n x^n + \sum_{n \geq 1} n! x^{n}  - \sum_{n \geq 1}n! x^{n}  &= 1 \\
1 - \sum_{n\geq 1}c_n x^n &= 1 \\
\sum_{n\geq 1}c_n x^n &= 0 \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

This would mean that every coefficient of $G(x)$ is zero, which is absurd.

Note that I substituted the coefficient of $G(x)F(x)$ with the combinatoric identity. I have approached the problem in many different ways (e.g. changing indices, constructing the inverse of $F(x)$ and comparing to $G(x)$) and I ultimately come to the same result.

I would appreciate if anyone could point out my error(s).

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_0=1$ and $a_n=-c_n$ for $n\ge 1$; then

$$\begin{align*}
\big(1-G(x)\big)\big(1+F(x)\big)&=\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}a_nx^n\right)\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}n!x^n\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{n\ge 0}\sum_{k=0}^na_k(n-k)!x^n\\\\
&=1\;,
\end{align*}$$

since

$$\sum_{k=0}^na_k(n-k)!=\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }n=0\\\\
n!-\sum\limits_{k=1}^nc_k(n-k)!=n!-n!=0,&\text{if }n\ge 1\;.
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

When you multiply
two series that start at
$x$,
the resulting series
starts at $x^2$,
not $x$.

Comment: If I define $\overline{F}(x)=1+F(x)$ and then multiply $(1-G(x))\overline{F}(x)$ in observance of the correction you mentioned, I am able to prove the identity. When I incorporate this into the calculation above, however, I get $1-\sum_{n \geq 1} c_{n} x^{n} +x=1$. Letting $c_{0}=1$, I get $1 - \sum_{n \geq 0} c_{n}=1$ and so $\sum_{n \geq 0} c_{n} = 0$. The series now includes the term $c_{0}$ but I don't see how this proves that they are multiplicative inverses.